# SQL query to bring linked record with lowest value in field

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Each news can have several pictures, which are ordered by the '**o**' field.

**news**

- id_news
- date_publish
- title

**pictures**

- id
- id_news
- filename
- o (order in which the pictures should be presented: 1, 2, 3...)

This query returns a list of news titles, along with the first picture for the thumbnail.

```
SELECT n.title, p.filename
FROM news as n
LEFT JOIN picture AS p ON (p.id_news = n.id_news AND p.o = 1)
ORDER BY date_publish DESC
```

The problem is that, because of the CMS, if the admin deletes the picture with o=1, the o=2 should take place in the previous query. So the question is: how do i add the filename of the first available picture in the news titles query? (it should be the picture record that has the lowest value in the field **o**)

Comment: Use P as a subquery limiting results to top 1 based on the join to news order the result by o asc.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid subqueries because they have significant impact when there are too many records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: I think a subquery - or additional query - is the only way to do this.   The subquery might look like `SELECT p.filename FROM p WHERE p.id_news = n.id_news ORDER BY p.o LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a different join here?

```
SELECT n.title, p.filename
FROM news as n
LEFT JOIN
picture p on 
(p.id_news = n.id_news)
inner join
(select id_news,min(o) o from picture) AS p1
ON (p1.id_news = n.id_news AND p1.o = p.o)
ORDER BY n.date_publish DESC
```

Comment: `partner` should be `picture`, I think